# How to obtain integral from a multidimensional array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave, numerical-integration

Let's say we have

```
A(:,:,1) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1


A(:,:,2) =

 2     2     2
 2     2     2
 2     2     2


A(:,:,3) =

 2     2     2
 3     3     3
 2     2     2
```

How would I perform an integral over each element along the 'page' (i.e. 'z') axis?

Our result matrix M should be 3 x 3, and for example:

`M(1:1)` would contain the integral of `A(1,1,1), A(1,1,2)` and `A(1,1,3)`.

`M(1:2)` would contain the integral of `A(1,2,1), A(1,2,2)` and `A(1,2,3)`.

And so on.

I'd like to get matrix `M` like this:

```
M = 
3.5    3.5    3.5
4      4      4 
3.5    3.5    3.5
```

Any idea how to do this? I've tried with `trapz` but no dice.

Comment: I can't see how, for example, A(1,1,:) calculates to 3.5. Do you just want to calculate the sum?

Comment: `trapz([1 2 2]) = 3.5` -- that is, taking the upper left value of each page, and so forth -- the other values were calculated accordingly--I don't want the sum, but the integral across each index -- Let me know your thoughts

Comment: This always depends on how your discrete data represents some continuous function. If the continuous function is the linear interpolant of these values the trapezoidal rule will give the exact integral. It could also represent a piecewise constant function, in which case you want the sum along the third dimension. There is no one correct answer, as you need to know what is your actual continuous function and there are lots of other possibilities than those simple ones I just mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the DIM parameter from trapz (this works in Octave):

```
A = bsxfun ("times", ones (3, 3), permute([1 2 2], [1, 3, 2]));
A(2, :, 3) = 3;
M = trapz (A, 3)
M =

   3.5000   3.5000   3.5000
   4.0000   4.0000   4.0000
   3.5000   3.5000   3.5000
```